# Keep iPhone unlocked while plugged in

Tags: iphone

I keep my iPhone protected with the locking mechanism but when I'm at home I like to attach it to my stereo and stream pandora or my itunes library. To answer the obvious question, running those things from my Mac just adds more clutter to my workspace so I like to unload those things.

Anyway, my droid had a feature that would allow you to set the phone to stay unlocked while plugged into a power source, unless locked manually.  I can't find anything like this on the iPhone.  Anyone know of something I'm missing?  Skipping songs and what not is really more of a process than it needs be do to having to unlock it every time.  And manually turning the auto-lock on and off all the time, ugh.  Too much work. :)

Comment: Probably a better question for SuperUser or the Apple beta.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about phone configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the iPhone, there's no need to unlock to skip a song, repeat a song, or change the volumne, or pause. Just double tap the Home Button and you can access those functions on the lock screen, without having to unlock the iPhone. Neat huh?

Comment: Yea, I know I can do that.  And that's ok with iTunes playing, but with pandora there's more to it.  I can't vote and I can't really see who's playing.  I just get back/play/pause/forward controls.  So somewhat limiting.  Voting your answer up because it is relevant.

Comment: Maybe I need to be complaining to the Pandora folks. :)

Comment: Well, you at least should have mentioned Pandora in your original post. You're right. The best you can do right now is talk to Pandora.

Comment: You might want to read my original post again. I *did* mention pandora.

Comment: ;) so you did. my bad. My answer still stands.

Answer (score 0):

I know that for my iPhone, when using the built in iTunes app, the phone will start to go to sleep ( I think I have it on a 5 min timeout ), and when a new song starts, it acts like someone touched it, and starts the countdown over again. I have Pandora but I'm not sure. And I don't believe there'd be an app capable of doing that on a non jail-broken phone.

Comment: Yea, that's what I have found out as well.  Currently, I'm going to set it to never lock automatically. I have a habit of hitting the lock button anyway, so it shouldn't be an issue, as long as it still dims after a period of time.

Answer (score 0):

Write a short/quicky app the does a

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES]
```

and run it when you're not actually playing with the Pandora UI.